# How can I pass underscore to \newcommand properly?

Tags: listings, external-files

I'd like to simplify my code appendix with this command definition:

```
\usepackage{listings}
% ...
\newcommand{\CodeListing}[1]{%
    \lstinputlisting[caption=#1]{#1}%
}
```

That is, the caption should be the file name. However, the caption argument and the file name argument seem to handle underscores differently. For the former, I need to escape them (`\_`), but for the latter, non-escaped underscores work fine. How can I solve this problem, if I only want to pass the file name once?

```
! Package Listings Error: File `spt2/my\T1\textunderscorefile(.m)' not found.
```

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\codelst}[1]{
    \lstinputlisting[caption=#1]{#1}
}
\codelst{/home/tim/projekt/matlab/path/save\_plot\_as.m}
\end{document}
```

which works fine for underscore-less paths.

Comment: Maybe: How can I work with an underscore without escaping?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's a very common problem: if you want to typeset an underscore, you need to pass `\_`, which is not good for a file name. Solution:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{listings}
\newcommand{\codelst}{\begingroup
  \catcode`_=12 \docodelst}
\newcommand{\docodelst}[1]{%
  \lstinputlisting[caption=\texttt{#1}]{#1}%
  \endgroup
}
\begin{document}
\codelst{/home/tim/projekt/matlab/path/save_plot_as.m}
\end{document}
```

It's better to say also `\texttt{#1}` so that the file name will be printed in typewriter font.

The idea is to change the `_` into a printable character, making it lose its special meaning. The trick consists in changing it *before* the argument is grabbed.

Comment: Thank you egreg! `\texttt` makes it nicer, too. Is it possible to do this in a single command definition? (Just curious)

Comment: @TimN It's possible, but the code would be quite intricate. TeX has more than enough space to contain a couple of macros. :) And actually you wouldn't save much (or even lose something) by doing the work with only one command.

Comment: Nice! Sadly, this does not seem to work inside environments defined with `NewEnviron` from `environ`; cf [mwe](http://pastebin.com/QMkac3c8).

Comment: @Raphael No, it can't work, because the category code is fixed as soon as the code for the `\NewEnviron` environment has absorbed its contents as an argument. There are workarounds, so maybe you can ask a new question.

Comment: [Done](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240410), thanks!

Comment: [Apparently](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/240417/3213) there is a simple, general (?) fix by adding `scantokens` to what you do.