# Problem with underscores in \newcommand

Tags: macros, cross-referencing

I am currently writing my thesis and I have each chapter as a separate project- I've been told I should join them up but I don't want to for now as I would find it overwhelming. I'd like to be able to reference labels of figures, tables, equations etc that are in other Chapters, i.e other projects, so that when I do eventually link up the chapters as a single project, the cross-referencing all works fine. If I add in the references as this stage, I obviously get warnings because the reference doesn't exist. What I would like to do is have a command that I can switch on and off which turns on and off these external references. I call this command `\refext` for 'external reference'.
Initially, I had code that looked like:

#### Option 1: Do nothing, I'm not ready, output the reference as words

```
\newcommand{\refext}[1]{Ref. #1}
```

#### Option 2: Yes, go ahead and reference up- I'm ready to compile all these things together as a single document:

```
\newcommand{\refext}[1]{\ref{#1}}
```

I would comment out the command I wasn't using, and in this way it was 'switchable' It would either print out the name of the label, or treat it as an ordinary reference.

This works, if the label is a single word. However this does not work if the label contains an underscore in the title- which all of my labels do.

After some reading, I have come across this answer which is similar to what I want to do: 
[How can I pass underscore to \newcommand properly?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38536/how-can-i-pass-underscore-to-newcommand-properly)

However, I have tried this and it doesn't work for me:

```
\newcommand{\refext}{\begingroup\catcode`\_=11 \dorefext}

\newcommand{\dorefext}[1]{\ref{#1}}
```

I get the error 'missing begin document' however of course I want to define my rules before I begin my document. The document compiles fine with all my other `\newcommand`s being in the same place.

Catcode 12 also doesn't work. I switched it out for 11 because I thought it might be better if it treated the underscore as text.

I don't really know what I'm doing here! I am not very adept with latex and I've entered into this new commands area a bit blind!  Help would be much appreciated- thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The underscore should do no harm when you use option 2; the problem is with option 1, where you can more simply do `\newcommand{\refext}[1]{Ref.~\detokenize{#1}}`

Comment: you could use `xr` package and reference into the other documents directly (although really it's simpler to make it all one document and use `\includeonly` when you are just working on a single chapter

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Underscores can be part of a label, but printing them is normally disallowed, because the underscore is used in running text for denoting subscripts in math formulas.

Option 2 should give no problem: you're just replacing `\ref` with `\refext`. For option 1, when you want to see the keys rather than the reference, you can do

```
\newcommand{\refext}[1]{Ref.~\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}}
```

The `\detokenize` command will, besides other things, make `_` printable. I added also `\texttt` in order to make the key more evident in the text.

Small example (I'll use option 2):

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\refext}[1]{Ref.~\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}}

\begin{document}

Here's some text where we cite \refext{some_thing} and go on

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Egreg!!! I've spend hours staring at this, trying more complicated solutions than necessary, and this is just such a simple and nice solution and works perfectly! Thank you for removing my growing headache!

Comment: Also thank you David for your help as well :). This is my first time posting on here and I'm very impressed and pleased at how helpful people are! I agree this is definitely the more elegant way to do things- I should have started it as one project from the very beginning that would have been far more sensible. Alas- my poor decisions, lack of knowledge and stubbornness have brought me to this point!