# Keeping underscores in parameters even inside NewEnviron environments

Tags: macros, environments, catcodes, parameters

I followed [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38537/3213) to define a command such that underscores in its parameter can be kept.

However, this does not work if the command is called inside an environment that has been defined with `NewEnviron` from `environ`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}
\newcommand{\cmd}{\begingroup
  \catcode`_=12 \cmdint}
\newcommand{\cmdint}[1]{%
  \texttt{#1}%
  \endgroup
}

\newenvironment{wrap}{}{}
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{wrap2}{\BODY}

\begin{document}
\cmd{some_test}

\begin{wrap}
  \cmd{some_test}
\end{wrap}

\begin{wrap2}
  \cmd{some_test}
\end{wrap2}
\end{document}
```

This compiles to

[image]

Say I can not do without `environ` (I've actually been struggling for about an hour to get rid of it in my actual document, without success), how can I fix this?

Comment: You want to have `verbatim` content then?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Not necessarily; I want to use it for `\input` but also for `\texttt`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution depends on the alphabet, used for the variables. If these are identifiers with upper and lower case letters, digits, underscore and some other harmless symbols (with category code 12/other, as punctuation chars) then `\detokenize` can be used to normalize the category codes of the identifier to token with category code 12 (same as digits):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}

\newcommand*{\cmd}[1]{\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}}

\newenvironment{wrap}{}{}
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{wrap2}{\BODY}

\begin{document}
\cmd{some_test}

\begin{wrap}
  \cmd{some_test}
\end{wrap}

\begin{wrap2}
  \cmd{some_test}
\end{wrap2}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Heh, that's actually the nicer fix for the original problem. Maybe you should post an answer to the [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38536/3213) I got this from?

Comment: How is this different from the approach with `scantokens`? Are there situations where you would prefer one over the other?

Comment: @Raphael `\detokenize` is easier in usage. It converts all characters to category code 12 and the space character to category code 10. `\scantokens` is more complicate, it's the equivalent from writing the contents to a file and reread it. End of line characters can cause unwanted white spaces unless disabled (`\errorcontextlines=-1`). Also the category codes for the characters, which an appear in the result has to be set to safe values.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that `detokenize` is indeed the better solution for my use case since the limitations don't bother me here.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like this is also a situation where `\scantokens` could come in nicely:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}
\newcommand{\cmd}{\begingroup
  \catcode`_=12 \cmdint}
\newcommand{\cmdint}[1]{%
  \texttt{\scantokens{#1\noexpand}}%
  \endgroup
}

\newenvironment{wrap}{}{}
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{wrap2}{\BODY}

\begin{document}
\cmd{some_test}

\begin{wrap}
  \cmd{some_test}
\end{wrap}

\begin{wrap2}
  \cmd{some_test}
\end{wrap2}
\end{document}
```

The problem with your original is that within a `\NewEnviron` type environment, the tokens have already been read in and their catcodes are already set before they get fed to your macro.  By using `\scantokens`, the catcodes are essentially reassigned.

For further details about using `\scantokens` @egreg has a nice explanation in response to my question at [Could someone further elucidate expansion, catcodes, and scantokens…?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/213713/22413)

Comment: How is this different from the approach with `detokenize`? Are there situations where you would prefer one over the other?

Comment: @Raphael Since I'll skip @HeikoOberdiek 's details.  With `\scantokens`, you can employ macros which will expand in the usual way:  so you could write somthing like `\scantokens{Hello \textbf{world}\empty}` and the `\textbf` will take effect: this would be difficult to achieve with `\detokenize`.  Of course, you shouldn't be using `\scantokens` alone like this.  I chose to use it because that would preserve the other structures you were already using and in the manner that you defined them.  `\detokenize` could potentially require you to rethink how your macros should be defined.

Comment: Thanks; it seems that `detokenize` is indeed the better solution for my use case (I only need a workaround for filenames with underscores), but yours is probably the one with general merit for [egreg's pattern](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38537/3213).