# Passing string containing "special" catcodes (especially `_`) to custom NewDocumentCommand command

Tags: macros, expl3, xparse

[How can I pass underscore to \newcommand properly?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38536/how-can-i-pass-underscore-to-newcommand-properly) suggests the solution is to use a zero-argument command that changes the catcode of `_`, before expanding to the actual command.

That's kind of the opposite of why I'd want to use  `\NewDocumentCommand`, as it's kind of awkward, and also obfuscating argument types.

Is there a way to pass strings containing underscores (file names, by the way) without leaving the comfort of my expl3/xparse/`\NewDocumentCommand` bubble?

I don't want to use `v` arguments; it should really function like a normal macro, `\includechapter{foo_bar}` and not like `\includechapter!foo_bar!`.

---

My code currently:

```tex
%%% Chapter Inclusion Macros
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
% Command to include chapter files, if
% either the exclusive chapter list is empty,
% or said chapter is in there
\cs_set:Npn \cel_includechapter:n #1 {
  % Check whether list is empty
  \clist_if_empty:NTF
  \g_cel_enabled_clist % which list
  {\include{#1/#1}} % if empty, just include
  { % else
    % check whether argument in list of enabled chapters
    \clist_if_in:NnTF 
    \g_cel_enabled_clist % in which list
    {#1} % which element to look for
    {\include{#1/#1}} % if in there
    {\chapter{#1~(currently~disabled)}} %if not in there
  }
}
% user-facing command \includechapter
% includes chaptername/chaptername
% if enabled
\NewDocumentCommand{\includechapter}{m}{
  \cel_includechapter:n{#1}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\enableChapter}{m}{
  \clist_put_right:Nn \g_cel_enabled_clist {#1}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

The build breaks when reaching

```tex
\includechapter{foo_bar}
```

with

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
                $
l.147 \includechapter{foo_bar}
```

Comment: Use v-type argument or detokenize. (each has its disadvantage, learn TeX for more details)

Comment: Actually... if egreg answer this, consider answering the *other* question then close this one as duplicate of that instead. Avoid scattering answers everywhere.

Comment: Turns out there's already a comment under that answer you link to for an... alternative approach. Check out if you want.

Comment: @user202729 What I meant with "staying in my bubble" would be to *not* use "atypical" `v`-verbatim-style tricks. Clarified in a question edit! Thanks for pointing it out, though. I'm not quite sure what you mean with "detokenize", but if that involves the zero-argument macro trick that I explicitly would like to avoid for the reasong given in my question, I'm afraid it's not a solution.

Comment: If it's about the interface, v-type in xparse (unlike \verb command) can use {...} too.

Comment: For detokenize, it's a macro defined in TeX... read https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20059/what-are-the-exact-semantics-of-detokenize maybe. TeX is a complex programming language.

Comment: hm, usrguide3.pdf says: *Thus a v-type argument is read between two identical char-
acters, which cannot be any of %, \, #, {, } or ␣.*, so I don't think `{foo_bar}` would work: not the same character, and not in the allowed set of characters.

Comment: Read the next statement in that same paragraph. Also you can try it out yourself

Comment: @user202729 My apologies, yes, you're right. Going to try it out!

Comment: Works, but now have to do more workarounds in other places. Interesting!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is where you say

```
{\chapter{#1~(currently~disabled)}} %if not in there
```

because an underscore in the file name would trigger math mode.

Solution: change into

```
{\chapter{\tl_to_str:n {#1}~(currently~disabled)}} %if not in there
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution in this case is to use `v`-type arguments:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\includechapter}{v}{
  \cel_includechapter:n{#1}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\enableChapter}{v}{
  \clist_put_right:Nn \g_cel_enabled_clist {#1}
}
```

This still requires more fixing, since the argument passed through needs to get processed before it can be typeset if it contains underscores.

Luckily, I don't want to use this macro as argument to another function (usrguide3.pdf):

> `v`: Reads an argument ‘verbatim’, between the following character and
> its next occurrence, in a way similar to the argument of the LATEX 2ε
> command `\verb`. Thus a `v`-type argument is read between two
> identical characters, which cannot be any of `%`, `\`, `#`, `{`, `}`
> or `␣`. The verbatim argument can also be enclosed between braces, `{`
> and `}`. **A command with a verbatim argument will produce an error
> when it appears within an argument of another function.**

Comment: By the way the "fixing" can be done with \scantokens if you know how

Comment: @user202729 I went with `\chapter{\protect\detokenize{#1}~(currently~disabled)}`